# Unable to convert the Ajax response (Laravel as backend) to an Excel (file being corrupted)

Tags: jquery, laravel

In my laravel project, I have to create an Excel file using "maatwebsite" package. It works successfully and a report is generated. I was required to download the Excel from the Ajax response. It works and the file is downloaded but the file is corrupted.

controller

```
$head = ['Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',"Content-Disposition" => 'attachment; filename="file.xlsx"'];
           
            return $this->excel->download(
                new ExportDataObject( // Export class
                    $data,
                    $headers,
                    "view_name",
                    "sheet",
                    ["header_widths" => [30,30,30,20,30]],
                    ["timezone" => ""]
                ),
                'TrpReport'.Date("dmY").'.xlsx',
                null,
                $head
            );
```

It works and I successfully downloaded the Excel file. After that, I tried the same with jQuery Ajax. I believe laravel returns stream data. It works and the file is downloaded, but it is corrupted.

jQuery (this is the code last I tried)

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/trips/download-report",
            data: { "id": 11 },
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN'  : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                "Accept": "application/octet-stream",
            },
            xhrFileds: {responseType: 'blob'},
            success: function (response) {                    
                var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = 'filename.xlsx';
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
```

When I click on the downloaded file it shows some error message (The file is corrupt and therefore cannot be opened.).
[image]

Thank you all for your support.

Comment: Open the generated file with a text editor and see what's in there. Real excel or error messages? Deep dive in your controller, dd what comes from `ExportDataObject`, before you send it to maatwebsite's download function. Make sure what's generated is correct, before you send it to the frontend

Comment: Typo ~ `xhrFileds` should be `xhrFields`. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have updated the "xhrFileds" with "xhrFields", and it works as I expected. Thank you all for your great support.

xhrFields: {responseType: 'blob'},